# How to enable SSLv1 in Java 8 Update 162

Tags: java, ssl

In work we have currently Windows 7 environment Java 7 Update 25 and this runs SSLv1 & SLLv3 fine but when upgrading to Java 8 Update 165 the option to enable SSLv3 is not available in the control panel.

I know with research that SSLv3 is automatically disabled due to security.

I have removed **SSLv3** from **jdk.tls.disableAlgorithms** in the java.security file & also added **deployment.security.SSLv1=true** and **deployment.security.SSLv3=true** to the deployment.properties file.

So from network traffic research the only protocol missing from Java 8 is **SSL** as Java 7 will have this in the network traffic and works fine.

What my question is in a windows client environment how to I enable SSLv1 in Java 8?

Also is this will help the error message we are getting is:

**javax.net.ssl.sslexception received fatal alert unexpected_message**

Comment: Anything lower than TLSv1.1 (and that includes ALL SSL Versions) should be considered broken and needs to be disabled. More and more libraries straight up remove the ability to support those protocols, so it's probably time to make sure that everything talks at least TLSv1.1. That shouldn't come as a shock to anyone, given that TLSv1.1 was release 13 years ago!

Comment: The application uses TLSv1.0 (won't use anything higher) I do understand the security implications but the application is supported through a different team I was wondering if there is a way to force enable SSLv1 in Java 8

Comment: There is no such thing as SSLv1 support. SSLv2 was the first public release of the protocol. Do you mean TLSv1 (which came after SSLv3)?

Comment: When analysing the network traffic between a working computer and non working computer accessing the application the only difference in protocol in network traffic (using Wireshark) is SSL but it didn't define the version WireShark but going of the release notes from Oracles it would probably be using SSLv3 as Java 7 has the option to enable or disable this where as Java 8 doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I managed to figure it out SSLv2 and SSLv3 can be enabled for all users via the deployment.properties file by these:

`# Advanced Security Settings\Use SSL 2.0 compatible ClientHello format`

`deployment.security.SSLv2Hello=true`

`deployment.security.SSLv2Hello.locked`

`# Advanced Security Settings\Use SSL 3.0`

`deployment.security.SSLv3=true`

`deployment.security.SSLv3.locked`

Seems like I was missing the .locked definitions in the deployment.properties file also found that using Java 8 Update 25 worked much better.

Also, as been advised the guy who commented there is no SSLv1.